# NSLock - should just block when locking a locked lock?

Tags: cocoa, nslock

I have a loop which starts with a

```
[lock lock];
```

because in the body of the loop I am creating another thread which needs to finish before the loop runs again. (The other thread will unlock it when finished).

However on the second loop I get the following error:

```
2011-02-02 07:15:05.032 BLA[21915:a0f] *** -[NSLock lock]: deadlock (<NSLock: 0x100401f30> '(null)')
2011-02-02 07:15:05.032 BLA[21915:a0f] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

The "lock" documentation states the following:

> Abstract: Attempts to acquire a lock, blocking a thread’s execution until the lock can be acquired. (required)

which makes me think it would just block until the lock could be acquired?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like two problems:

- Locking a lock on one thread and unlocking on another is not supported – you probably want `NSCondition`. Wait on the `NSCondition` in the parent thread, and signal it in the child thread.
- A normal `NSLock` can’t be locked while already locked. That’s what `NSRecursiveLock` is for.

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to send `-unlock` when you were done? Each call to `-lock` must be paired with a call to `-unlock`.